# "row_id" on Playa field not working

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

I'm trying to get the current "row_id" of a Playa entry, but it doesn't seem to want to output.

I'm prefixing it because there was another plugin that was conflicting with the {count} and {total_results} variables.

So my code looks like this:

```
{cf_course_content var_prefix="q" limit="1" offset="{course_progress_id}"}
     {q:count}
     {q:total_results}
     {q:row_id}
     {q:cf_question_type}
{/cf_course_content}
```

But when this is rendered, it looks like this:

```
1
15
{row_id}
Drag & Drop
```

Why would it output like that? When all the other prefixed variables are working. I've pulled this outside of any other plugins / modules just incase anything was clashing and it still does this.

I've also been doing a bit of digging, and i'm not sure if "row_id" is what I need to output anyway.

I'm trying to get the "Row Position" inside the Playa field. But I believe the "row_id" is a unique reference from the DB? Not Unique to that particular entry.

Is there any way to output this, or get around the "row_id" problem?

Comment: Aren't you looking simply for {count} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{row_id}` is a Matrix tag. Playa doesn’t know anything about it. To get the current entry’s position within the Playa field, just use `{count}` (or `{q:count}` since you’ve got that var_prefix param.

Comment: Will the {q:count} not just output "1" though, if i'm limiting it to only 1 Playa entry? 

Ideally I want to be able to get the ID of the position it is in, in Playa.

Comment: Sorry, there’s no tag to get a single entry’s position within the Playa field, if you’re taking it out of context :-/